# Getting error trying to display string split on new lines - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<% @recipe.instructions.each do |instruction| %>
  <li><%= instruction %></li>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error: undefined method 'each' for `#<String:0xa354eb8>`

@recipe.instructions is defined as text

Please help!

Reese

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `each_line` instead of `each`. `String#each` has been removed in ruby 1.9, `each_line` works with all ruby versions.

Answer (score 1):

What about `String#each_line`? It should work with both Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.